# Javascript getElementById

Tags: javascript, php

I've written a php script with simple security-token system, And I used the security-token in a GET way simple example :

```
 <form action="index.php?act=members&add=member&sec-hash=b0af595dc70755564889457afad47def" method="post" target="add_member" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

But I've had a problem with Javascript, while trying to get it to send add some easier way for me to add&edit members, but I couldn't get it from the `<form>` to use it in other Javascript things :S

this is what I've tried :

```
document.writeln('<iframe id="iframe" src="http://localhost/panel/index.php?act=members&add=member"onload="read()"></iframe>');
function read()
{
var securitytoken=
document.getElementById("iframe").contentDocument.forms[0].add_member.value;
document.writeln('<form action="add.php?sec-hash='+securitytoken+'" method="POST">');
....extra Javascript code ...
}
```

please, and its hard for me to re-code the script, I mean its easier for me to try with Java first you feel me ?

Thanks from now :)

Comment: Did you mean extra javascript code or extra PHP code?

Comment: You could use an AJAX request to the PHP script. You could then handle the response in JavaScript (side note: Java != JavaScript). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery

Comment: @AustinMullins I meant extra javascript code,

Comment: @noahnu I'll take a look, and my bad it was a mistake when i said JAVA. Thank you, though

Comment: Still didn't find anything :(

Comment: I need to get the action value, from '<form>'

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding what you want. You want to be able to run the `PHP` script 'add.php' with the security token from your iFrame?

Comment: @noahnu exactly, And if only I could grab the token from the '<form>' using the iFrame. That would be very helpful :D

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the `<form>` located in an `iFrame`:

```
var frm = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
```

To then retrieve the `action` attribute:

```
var act = frm.getAttribute('action');
```

And to parse for the security token:

```
var securityToken = act.substring(act.indexOf("sec-hash=") + 9);
```

If I were you, I'd add some error handling / if statements to check if each string/element you are working with isn't null/empty/undefined.